# AppEngine Download Graph

Tags: java, google-app-engine, analytics

I use AppEngine to host an Eclipse update site. I would like to keep track of the number of downloads of each version over time. Searching for ".*plugins.*jar" in the AppEngine access logs gives me a rough idea but the logs only go back a couple of months.

Is there any easy library which I can use to graph my downloads? I'm sure I could roll my own but I would like to have pretty graphs and feel like this may be a problem which has already been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented some code which met my requirements. I haven't packaged it nicely but you can start by looking at these files:

- https://github.com/mchr3k/org.intrace/blob/master/intrace.appengine/war/downloads.jsp
- https://github.com/mchr3k/org.intrace/blob/master/intrace.appengine/src/org/gaecounter/CountDownloadsFilter.java
- https://github.com/mchr3k/org.intrace/blob/master/intrace.appengine/src/org/gaecounter/data/Counter.java
- https://github.com/mchr3k/org.intrace/blob/master/intrace.appengine/war/WEB-INF/web.xml

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any libraries that would do the tracking for you on downloads on GAE. But if you decide to log the downloads yourself I would suggest using [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart) to visualize the data. It's really easy to build really nice looking charts. I especially like the playground where you can quickly try different charts.